Does painting or staining a fence make it last longer?
I commonly come across the opinion that if you regularly apply paint or a stain to a wooden fence it will last longer but there appears to be no hard evidence.
Knowing that this is not enough to make this question on topic for Skeptics, I've found a couple of claims from commercial entities.  The first is "The home finisher", in the article Does Staining a Wood Fence Make it Last Longer? they make the following claims

Moisture resistant stain can extend the life of a wood fence from around 10 years to over 20 years, if properly maintained

Another company "Fence Armour" in the article Protecting Your Wood Fence: Why Staining Is Essential makes the claim

Staining your wood fence is not just about enhancing its appearance; it is a vital step in protecting and prolonging the life of your investment. By applying a high-quality stain, you can preserve the natural beauty of your wood fence, enhance its durability, prevent damage, and ensure its longevity.

No doubt there are more claims like this to be found.
So does staining or painting extend the life of a wood fence? If so for how long? Also the answer needs to speak directly to the increased lifespan.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

TL/DR: Yes, an appropriate and well applied paint or stain will make wood last longer outside when exposed to the elements by protecting it against the various interwoven processes that degrade the structure over time.
This is widely reported on in the scientific literature.  An example I like from 1990 published by the USDA discuses this with references and also a discussion of weathering processes with pictures.  This is what they say on paints and stains:

Paints. Film-forming finishes such as paint have long been used to protect wood surfaces. Of all the finishes, paints offer the greatest degree of protection against erosion by weathering and the widest selection of colors. A nonporous paint film retards penetration of moisture and thereby reduces paint discoloration by wood extractives, paint peeling and checking, and warping of the wood (4, 98, 99). Proper pigments will essentially eliminate photodegradation of the wood surface. However, paint is not a preservative; it will not prevent decay if conditions are favorable for fungal growth.
Stains. When pigments are added to water-repellent or WRP solutions or to similar penetrating transparent wood finishes, the mixture is classified as a pigmented, semitransparent, penetrating stain (1, 2, 4, 112, 136). The pigment provides color and greatly increases the durability of the finish because UV light is partially blocked. These semitransparent stains permit much wood grain to show through; they penetrate the wood to some extent without forming a discrete, continuous layer, Therefore, they will not blister or peel, even if excessive moisture enters the wood. The durability of any stain system is a function of pigment content, resin content, preservative, water repellent, and quantity of material applied to the wood surface. The performance of stains during outdoor exposure has received a great deal of attention (137–143).
Penetrating stains are suitable for both smooth and rough surfaces. How- ever, their performance is markedly improved if applied to roughsawn, weathered, or rough-textured wood (4, 96, 99, 112, 136, 137, 141–144) because more material can be applied to such surfaces. They are especially effective on lumber and plywood that does not hold paint well, such as flat- grained and weathered surfaces, or dense species. Penetrating stains can be used effectively to finish such exterior surfaces as siding, trim, exposed decking, and fences. Stains can be prepared from both solvent borne resin systems and latex systems; however, waterborne (latex) systems do not penetrate the wood surface. Commercial finishes known as heavy-bodied, solid color, or opaque stains are also available, but these products are essentially similar to paint because of their film-forming characteristics. Such “stains” do find wide success when applied on textured surfaces and panel products such as hardboard. They can be oil based or latex based.

Specific details of lifespan by treatment and wood type are provided by Williams, R. Sam. "Finishing of wood." Wood Handbook (2010): 16-39.:


Does this talk about longevity directly, it seems to be talking about wood surface penetration which may or mayu not connect

"retards penetration of moisture and thereby reduces paint discoloration by wood extractives, paint peeling and checking, and warping of the wood" (just to pick one example) doesn't require a lot of dot-connecting to get to longevity.

@AdamHyland maybe, even without a stain fences can last a pretty long time, I saw one in pretty bad condition, with no maintenance still in place after 10 years.  I don't know that staining would have improved its condition.  It got rained on plenty of times, I also see stained fences becoming visibly soaked through

@user1605665 and what timber was that fence made of/what treatment did it have applied at first? I'd expect that it was pressure treated (with decay-inhibiting chemicals, possibly ones you wouldn't want to handle) and quite possibly stained as well.  Your title doesn't include "regularly", neither does the quote in the answer.

@user1605665 The full answer would be the linked 36 page document.  Figure 8 is a summary of the primary mechanisms and their interaction.  All the statements are backed up with references, that should provide more details on any particular point.

Note that the Forest Products Lab in Wisconsin has done a lot of the best research on economic uses of wood, from strength to structures to weathering to coatings. That's the first place I would look if I wanted actual evidence.

Unfortunately this would appear to completely useless - it's a comparison between the two types of finish.  Not one iota of information is given regarding the question asked.

@user1605665 If you follow the link to the 1990 article and read the whole thing, and especially if you follow the chain of citations in that article, you'll have far more detailed information than I expect you could want on how exposed wood ages, what causes the aging, how finishing mitigates the effects of those causes, how long finishes last indoors and outdoors, etc., etc. It wouldn't be reasonable to reproduce all the details here. I do agree that this answer might benefit from clearly stating that yes, finishing wood (appropriately) protects the wood from damage by the elements.

@ToddWilcox Good point, added.

I don't have the full text of this paper but some types of (natural) oils polymerize and form a layer that protects against white rot (fungi), according to the experiments therein.

The oil-coated samples were then placed on agar petri dishes that were spread with white-rot fungi. The areas of growth inhibition were measured over several days using an agar diffusion assay. The results showed that all oil-based coatings inhibited the fungal growth, with tung oil being the most effective followed by linseed and soybean oils.

OTOH, blood-based paint that was also sometimes used in the past doesn't seem to help with that.
As discussed e.g. in this FAO document, paints by themselves typically are only mildly fungicidal, but can be so enhanced with various additives known as "wood preservatives". (This last document doesn't contain experiments as such.)
Evaluation of paints under outdoors conditions is more complicated than measuring fungi growth in a lab though. The paints themselves degrade under UV exposure etc. Nonetheless, paint does help, more so if the solvent is not water, apparently. For papers of that kinds see e.g. this other paper:

After a long exposure to light, heat, oxygen, mechanical stress, moisture and environmental pollutants is known that the physical and chemical properties of the polymeric systems degrade gradually. The principal cause of paint degradation is exposure at solar radiation. The UV-A range and the UV-B range with wavelengths of 400–315 nm and 315–280 nm are not absorbed by the atmosphere and their energy falls within the bond dissociation energy range of many polymers (240–400 nm). The reactions that appear after prolonged exposure to solar radiation are chain scission, cross-linking, and further oxidation reactions. Changes in the polymeric structure are caused by these reactions, and in consequence, takes place the modification of the mechanical properties and the chemical stability of the paint.
[...] Studies tackling the natural ageing of different types of coatings used for wood protection are less common in literature because they are more difficult to conduct. [...] Lestari et al. analysed the influence of exposure to environmental factors for six months of samples of common Indonesian wood species, i.e. teak and pine. Both untreated and treated samples were exposed, the latter being coated with ultra lasur coating systems containing water repellents and/or fungicide substances. Coating quality begins to diminish during the very first week of exposure due to the high level of radiation intensity. The untreated wood was also found to get more discoloration and to be more easily covered by fungi than the treated samples. The best results were achieved in terms of moisture absorption in the case of wood treated with solvent-based paints.

Wood itself suffers from (slower) abiotic degradation under UV (as well as temperatures over 65C), BTW, even if you prevent all fungi growth.  Generally (from that paper), clear-coat finishes (optically transparent so you can see the wood through) provide less UV protection to the wood itself.
